# convert c# button click to script

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery-ui, button

can anyone help me get converting this C# code to script?

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["ctrl"] = Panel1;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onclick", "<script language=javascript>window.open('Print.aspx','PrintMe','height=300px,width=300px,scrollbars=1');</script>");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to make this be normal html / javascript it's just an onclick event of a button.  However, by changing this to javascript you are losing the set of the session variable "ctrl".  This might be used by other parts of your application.  If you don't care about that then you can just change to a regular html button.  If you do care about the session variable then you have to use server side code such as c# to set the session variable such as the c# code that you had posted above.

I would read it as:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" name="button1" value="Button" onclick="javascript:window.open('Print.aspx','PrintMe','height=300px,width=300px,scrollbars=1');" />
```

You can also wrap the click event into a function if you wanted tidy up your html code.

If you don't like having the javascript in the button you can always bind the onclick with javascript before hand.

For example if you have the jquery library you can just do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#button1").on("click","window.open('Print.aspx','PrintMe','height=300px,width=300px,scrollbars=1'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you Avitus, it helped, But how to control the session ctrl on click event, please help the same, The "panel1" has set of textboxes and label in it.

Comment: The best part of this answer is you could lose the ctrl

Comment: +1 loss of control I didn't even see that.  In order to set a session variable you have to have an action on the server side of things such as the c# code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in the aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openPopUp()
    {
    window.open('Print.aspx','PrintMe','height=300px,width=300px,scrollbars=1');
    }
</script>
```

Then you do on the button

```
<asp:Button ... onClientClick="openPopUp() onClick="btnClick"/>
```

You can have both a client event and a server side event.

```
protected void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["ctrl"] = Panel1;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Nick.I'm controlling a session variable on the click event. please help with the same.

Comment: Check my updated response. You can have two events. One for server side and one for the client side

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Html DOM ID with `<%=Button1.ClientID%>`

Using jQuery you'd get:

```
$(function() {
    $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function() {
        window.open(...)
    });
});
```

Of course, perhaps you do not want to use a server control and keep the button and behavior on the client side.

```
<input type='button' value='Button' id='Button1' />
```

And then use the same construct as above: `$("Button1").click(...)`